# Enable HTTPS traffic for WCF Service. Issue with changing traffic http to https

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-config

**The issue is:** I tried to change WCF service traffic from HTTP to HTTPS. But I am not able to access this service, I am getting 404 error. I saw some blogs saying that we need to add the custom binding. but I am not getting.

Please, help me with this.
Below is my web config for default HTTP binding.

I want this to change to HTTPS.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp helpEnabled="True" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />

    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Just a question, but are you hosting this service in IIS?

Comment: Yes  hosting in Azure.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can just configure azure to host the service on 443 SSL port. You will need a certificate though.

Comment: Without Certificate, I can able to change http traffic to https for Web application UI part. In case of WCF only I am not able to. For WCF we must need SSL certificate?

Comment: I was under the impression a SSL/TSL certificate is also required for any other Web Application (if you are using https).

Comment: Azure Protocol settings, If I enable an option called "HTTPS Only" then I can able to serve my application in https traffic. But if I call my WCF service I am getting 404 error.

Comment: And you are calling it at an `https://` address?

Comment: Yes I am calling it an https

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179316/discussion-between-sharad-and-stefan).

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following code below the `<behaviors>` tag and working like a champ.

```
<bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```